# (Lack of) Ambiguous Type When Using Read and Show in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, ambiguous-call

I wrote a very simple Haskell program:

```
main = print $ sum $ map read ["55", "99", "101"]
```

Given my past experience, I expected to get an "ambiguous type" error, since the signature of `sum $ map read [...]` is `(Read a, Num a) => a`; `Num` is a class and thus cannot itself implement the `Show` class.  However, the program correctly outputted "255".  How was `print` able to determine the method of producing the output?  (`show` also is able to produce the correct result with no error.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the `-fwarn-type-defaults` option you'll get this:

```
$ ghc -O2 -fwarn-type-defaults ddd.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ddd.hs, ddd.o )

ddd.hs:2:8: Warning:
    Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type ‘Integer’
      (Show s0) arising from a use of ‘print’ at ddd.hs:2:8-12
      (Read s0) arising from a use of ‘read’ at ddd.hs:2:26-29
      (Num s0) arising from a use of ‘sum’ at ddd.hs:2:16-18
    In the expression: print
    In the expression: print $ sum $ map read ["55", "99", "101"]
    In an equation for ‘main’:
        main = print $ sum $ map read ["55", "99", "101"]
```

which explains what is going on.